# Understanding mixed trigger avalanche breakdown in pn junctions

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I am reading a device physics text (Sze *Physics of Semiconductor Devices*, 3e, Chapter 2.4.3) and I am trying to make sense of the discussion of avalanche breakdown.

The discussion is (over?)simplified by assuming that we have *only* a hole trigger current (We are in reverse bias, so this trigger current is physically arising from generation in the region just outside the depletion region on the n-side, where hole concentrations are below their equilibrium values. We are here tacitly neglecting generation in the depletion region in assuming that this trigger current is purely injected from $x = 0$.) From there, I can follow the derivation which leads to the standard condition for breakdown, but I am confused about how electrons (which are being extracted from the p-side) enter here. My questions are therefore twofold:

(1) In the attached, Sze claims (and the given reference 13 is simply a private communication with someone named PJ Lundberg) that the breakdown conditions with respect to both holes and electrons as triggers (99a,b) "are equivalent". What does this mean? Obviously, in a real pn junction in reverse bias (even one which is abrupt and one-sided due to the other being heavily-doped) we have extraction of carriers from both sides. Am I then to understand that Sze/Lundberg are claiming that *irrespective of the magnitude of the given trigger currents* (for example, in a p+n junction we will have that the holes trigger current in from the n-side is much higher), whichever of 99a,b are reached first gives us breakdown? If so, is this something I should expect? It would seem (counterintuitively to me) to suggest that we could still have electron-trigger current-induced breakdown even in a very strongly p+n diode if the $\alpha_p, \, \alpha_n$ in the given material conspired to make the equation in 99b true before that of 99a?

(2) If my understanding in (1) is correct, then indeed Sze/Lundberg are claiming that when we have two different trigger currents in a region we can simply "add" their effects. That is, we can consider them separately. Why is this situation linear in this way? I believe this is what's assumed when Sze writes

> The situation does not change when a mixed primary current initiates the breakdown, so either Eq. 99a or Eq. 99b gives the breakdown condition.

[image]
[image]
[image]